# Rails project can not be created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, aptana3

I want to create a Rail project named `Pierre` with Aptana Studio 3 but it's written :

> Pierre@PC-Pierre ~
>   $ rails new .
>   Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
>   Type 'rails' for help.

I have joined a screenshot of the repository where I created my project. Could someone help me to deal with that ? [image][image]

Comment: Just for clarification: You tried running `rails new pierre`, right?

Comment: @Severin I created a Rails project called 'Pierre' but it did not create automatically all the "default" files as expected but directly show the error message as above

Comment: @Severin Do you have any idea on how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Did you try running the same command outside of Aptana?

Comment: It seems to work. There are a lot of things that are "created" and the last line is 'Bundle complete' when I run it in the terminal. How should I do to run it in Aptana Studio 3 ?

Comment: @Severin when I open Aptana Studio I don't know how to open the project I created through the terminal

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/324183/how-can-i-import-an-existing-project-in-aptana-without-moving-the-files

Comment: @Severin Oh ! That seems to work ! Thanks a lot ! I guess seeing the folders on the left guarantees that it is ok... Is there a simple way to check if all is fine without making code ?

Comment: If you run the app server with `rails s` and `localhost:3000` gives you the Rails page you're all set :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165145/discussion-between-mysteryguy-and-severin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue you are describing comes from Aptana and not Rails. Create the App from cmd and then import it into Aptana like so: https://superuser.com/questions/324183/how-can-i-import-an-existing-project-in-aptana-without-moving-the-files